# Adding an End of Week Column (Ending Saturday) in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

So I'm struggling to add a column for End of Week- Saturday to my dataset.
I've created a solution in the Data View area of Power BI using the following formula:

Week End Date = Data[txn_time] - WEEKDAY(Data[txn_time], 1) +7

which gives me the correct outcome.

But when going onto Power Query I run into a problem.
The first problem is that when achieving a Week Ending Saturday column, it doesn't take into consideration the days that are Saturdays themselves and creates a Week Ending Saturday a week ahead, rather than the current date itself.
Another issue is that the week ending doesn't take into account the different months, and instead of e.g. Sunday 29th March giving me the following Saturday, it will give me Saturday 28th March as end of week

These are the headers for the columns that I have

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwXCH.png)

I've tried The column function: End of Week and taking away 1 from it to give me all the Saturdays, but it doesn't take into consideration the days that are already Saturday.

I'm bad at explaining, but im happy to answer any questions.

Simply, i'm trying to figure out how to add a Week Ending Saturday column, that takes into account days that are already on a Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to specify the first day of the week in the `Date.EndOfWeek` function.

The Custom Column Formula would be:

```
 = Date.EndOfWeek([txn_time],Day.Sunday)
```

*Example with dates as m/d/y*
[image]

To reproduce the above, paste the following M Code into a blank query in the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromColumns(
        {List.Dates(#date(2023,1,1), 10, #duration(1,0,0,0))},
        type table[txn_time=date]),
    
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", 
        each Date.EndOfWeek([txn_time],Day.Sunday), type date)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```